# get ip address of all connected pc in c#

Tags: c#, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get ip address of all pc on my pc which is connected in lan in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360497/get-ip-address-of-all-pc-on-my-pc-which-is-connected-in-lan-in-c)

This is my code.I give only ip address of my computer but i want to ip address of all computer which is connected in lan.also i give the troubleshoot error in this code. please give me the solution with changes of code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd ";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C net view";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    String output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\n' };
    String strHostName = string.Empty;

    string[] s = output.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
    IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;



    p.WaitForExit();
    int z = s.Length - 5;


    string[] str1 = new string[z];
    int i = 0;
    char[] saperator = { ' '};
    for (int j = 3; j < s.Length - 2; j++, i++)
    {

        str1[i] = (s[j].ToString()).Split(saperator)[0] ;
        Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString());
    }
     //Console.WriteLine(output);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's not working? Are you not able to get the output from the NET VIEW command? Are you not able to parse the entries? Is the DNS not resolving?  What error are you experiencing and where is it occurring?

Comment: Seems like we have a closing loop. This question is being closed because it's a duplicate of another, and *that* question is already closed because it's a duplicate of this one. And now there's a third instance of the question being closed because it's a duplicate of these two . . .

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly a professional but i think what you need is called a port scanner, you can implement the very basic functionality of a port scanner into your app and read all the live ips in your network

one solution would be:
http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial142_Creating-a-Port-Scanner-with-Csharp.html

they even have code available for download on the site. haven't tried downloading it tough. :)